# Why should we use character entities for symbols in HTML?

Tags: html

I accept some of the symbols, we have to use character entities. But what is the difference to use `&#38;` and & or `&gt;` and > and some of them which is available in keyboard.

Just for knowledge purpose.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

The only characters you need to use character references for are `<` (start of tag), `&` (start of character reference), `"` (start/end of attribute value) and `'` (ditto), and then only in places where they have special meaning.

e.g. `<` means "start of tag" in many parts of an HTML document, so you have to use `&lt;` if you want to express "less than symbol" instead.

Comment: Surely you mean `&lt;` and not `&gt;` "less than", not "greater than"?

Answer (score 0):

Character entities are used to display reserved characters in HTML.
`<` , `&` are reserverd charcters .